# Not able to select value - error "Select only works on <select> elements, not on <a>"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve all possible year, model and make from [https://www.osram-americas.com/en-us/applications/automotive-lighting-systems/Pages/lrgmain.aspx]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.osram-americas.com/en-us/applications/automotive-lighting-systems/Pages/lrgmain.aspx")
# Switch to new window opened
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
# Close the new window
driver.close()
# Switch back to original browser (first window)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#fldYear a.sbToggle")
el.click()
select = Select(el)
select.select_by_visible_text("2016")
```

However if I try to select year 2016. It is giving error :
Select only works on `<select>` elements, not on `<a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need `selenium` and automate any visual interactions to get the year+make+model data from the page and can approach the problem with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) only making appropriate GET requests:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

import requests

year = 2016
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36'}
    session.get("https://www.osram-americas.com/en-us/applications/automotive-lighting-systems/Pages/lrgmain.aspx")

    while True:
        response = session.get("https://www.osram-americas.com/_Layouts/Sylvania.Web.LRGHandler/LRGHandler.ashx",
                               params={"rt": "fetchmake", "year": str(year)})

        data = response.json()
        if not data:  # break if no makes in a year
            break

        for make in data:
            response = session.get("https://www.osram-americas.com/_Layouts/Sylvania.Web.LRGHandler/LRGHandler.ashx",
                                   params={"rt": "fetchmodel", "year": str(year), "make": make["Id"]})

            for model in response.json():
                d[year][make["Value"]].append(model["Value"])

        year -= 1

pprint(dict(d))
```

Comment: Can you please help with explanation of this approach. Specially I am lost after while true : part. one liner comment will be good. Also may I know some nice article/read for session.get.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara sure, the "while true" helps to iterate year over year back into the past up until there are no makes for a specific year - this is where we break checking the contents of the response. The requests "session" helps to [maintain the web-scraping session here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1792/web-scraping-with-python/8152/maintaining-web-scraping-session-with-requests). Hope that helps.

Comment: @alexce how you come to know that Sylvania.Web.LRGHandler/LRGHandler.ashx is available. i am not able to find that in page source.

Comment: @BhaveshGhodasara ah, that part. I've opened up the developer tools (network tab) and looked what requests were being sent while I select values in the dropdowns.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your current approach is that you are finding the `a` element and trying to use it as a `select` element. [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) will only work with `select` elements.

Note that in this case, it's easier to get to the invisible `select` element and get the years from its options directly:

```
options = [option.get_attribute("innerText") for option in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("select#ddlYear option")[1:]]
print(options)
```

The `[1:]` slice here is to skip the very first `Select Year` element.

---

Complete working code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.osram-americas.com/en-us/applications/automotive-lighting-systems/Pages/lrgmain.aspx")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
toggle = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#fldYear a.sbToggle")))
toggle.click()

options = [option.get_attribute("innerText") for option in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("select#ddlYear option")[1:]]
print(options)
```

Prints:

```
[u'2016', u'2015', u'2014', u'2013', u'2012', u'2011', u'2010', u'2009', u'2008', u'2007', u'2006', u'2005', u'2004', u'2003', u'2002', u'2001', u'2000', u'1999', u'1998', u'1997', u'1996', u'1995', u'1994', u'1993', u'1992', u'1991', u'1990', u'1989', u'1988', u'1987', u'1986', u'1985', u'1984', u'1983', u'1982', u'1981', u'1980', u'1979', u'1978', u'1977', u'1976', u'1975', u'1974', u'1973', u'1972', u'1971', u'1970', u'1969', u'1968', u'1967', u'1966', u'1965', u'1964', u'1963', u'1962', u'1961', u'1960', u'1959', u'1958', u'1957', u'1956', u'1955']
```